# intelliJ not working on El capitan 10.11

Tags: macos, java, operating-systems, intellij-idea

I just installed the new OS El capitan 10.11 and discovered that intelliJ isn't working on it.

When I launch it, I get this error:

```
"This application requires the legacy Java SE 6 runtime which is unavailable for this version of OS X."
```

I'm guessin that Java hasn't been set up properly yet. Does anybody have any ideas on how I can make this work?

Comment: [You can properly setup Java.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19533528/installing-java-on-os-x-10-9-mavericks)  Based on the error it looks like its looking for a legacy installation and 10.11 isn't going to have an unsupported legacy version of Java.  What version of IntelliJ are you using that still requires that legacy version of Java?

Comment: Running intelliJ 13. Not sure why it would require a legacy. Is that something I can change?

Comment: As of 2013 the installer still required [1.6](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/27854363-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks) so try adding 1.6 and see if it works.  Also [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006136/intellij-idea-13-uses-java-1-5-despite-setting-to-1-7)

Comment: Can't install 1.6 (official Apple java), it's not supported in 10.11 :(

Comment: So upgrade to an IDE that doesn't require it or downgrade to 10.10.x

Comment: @denislexic which version of IntelliJ do you use ?

Comment: Java 6 for El Capitan: https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you did an upgrade of an 10.10 install where everything still worked fine (and where the Apple-supplied java 6 runtime was installed), the following solution might work. I had the same problem as you had, and this solved my issues:

1. Quit IntelliJ and go to the Applications-folder in Finder
2. Right-click the IntelliJ.app and choose: Show package contents
3. Open the Contents-folder (this was the only file/folder in my case)
4. Open the Info.plist file using a text-editor of some kind (TextEditor should do the job, but I prefer using Sublime for such tasks).
5. Find the following tag:

   ```
   <key>JVMVersion</key>
   <string>1.6*,1.7+</string>
   ```
6. Remove `1.6*,` from the string-tag, so it becomes:

   ```
   <key>JVMVersion</key>
   <string>1.7+</string>
   ```
7. Save the file, and try to start IntelliJ again.

As I said, this seems to work for me. I do have to note that I am using IntelliJ 14, but I think this process should work for 13 as well.

Also, when a more permanent solution from Apple comes out, it might be a good idea to undo these steps (just add the removed text again) or reinstall IntelliJ completely.

Comment: Awesome, worked! I changed it to 1.8* and worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Does not work for me at all ... edited the file, still the same blocking dialog (idea 14)

Answer (score 4):

I simply reinstalled Java 6 from this Apple link https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US and IntelliJ 14 was able to recognize it.  This also allows me to continue using Java 1.6 in Intellij.

More here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827627-IDE-doesn-t-start-after-updating-to-Mac-OS-Yosemite-or-Mavericks

From Jetbrains support:

> JDK 1.6 is required to run and may be missing on your system. Please install Apple JDK 1.6. There should be a window with the suggestion to install Java when you start the product for the first time, but it could be hidden by other application windows.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.